# How do convert lat/lon to UTM in python using pyproj?

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, utm

Hello I am trying to covert `Lat` and `Long` to `UTM` using the package `pyproj` but I ma having the following trouble by trying to convert coordinates of a locality in Germany.

```
from pyproj import Proj
myProj = Proj("+proj=utm +zone=23K, +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

If I do

```
myProj(44.64104, 11.2278) =
(17049859.412484482, 16805739.561948165)
```

But if I do

```
myProj(48.638667,11.458702) = 
(1e+30, 1e+30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing zone:

```
myProj = Proj("+proj=utm +zone=33 +north +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

Comment: Just a note, lat=44.64104, lon=11.2278 resides in UTM zone 32T (not 33)